# How to handle fallback when a language is missing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a localized WinForms app and the default locale is set German (`de-DE`). I've added 2 new locales (`en-GB` and `en`).

To get a particular culture info I do:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
```

When the app is installed and the user's current culture is for example, `en-US`, how should I handle a fallback to match the other locale I have available, ie. `en` ?

When doing:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
```

The culture is not found and it falls back to my default locale.

Comment: Can't you just catch a `CultureNotFoundException`?

Comment: `en` is supported from Windows 7, according to [LCID reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c)